# WebStorm + running Meteor => no auto-completing code?

Tags: meteor, autocomplete, webstorm

I'm using WebStorn for developing, but since yesterday the code auto-completation is just working, when my meteor app is not running. Thereby it does not matter if I'm running it via run configuration or simply by typing „meteor“ in console. Just the fact that meteor is running on my maschine seems to deactivate the code suggestions from WebStorm. When using STRG+SPACE its still there, but it is not automatically showing up anymore.

I'm on Win7x64 with WebStorm 11.0.3

Comment: can't recreate. Does auto-completion work if meteor is not running? A supposition: may be, meteor process takes too much CPU/memory, so that auto-completion is slow to appear?

Comment: Yes, if i stop meteor its back again. I have just 12% CPU usage while launching and 1% when running. Do not thinks thats the problem. After i reinstalled WebStorm it was working for about 5 hours, now gone again